Shadows of partitions of lcm
$\DeclareMathOperator\lcm{lcm}$Fix an integer $n\geq1$. Denote the least common multiple $L_n=\lcm(1,2,\dots,n)$.

QUESTION.  Is the following true? For each integer partition $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots)\vdash 2L_n$ whose parts satisfy $\lambda_i\leq n$ there exists a partition $\mu=(\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots)\vdash L_n$ such that for each part $\mu_j$ there is a part $\lambda_i$ for which $\mu_j=\lambda_i$ for some $i$. The latter condition means
$$\{\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots\} \subseteq \{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots\}$$
when regarded as multisets.

Remark. Another way to look at this is: the problem requires splitting a partition of $2L_n$ into two partitions of $L_n$.
Postscript. Just a remark: I'm convinced that instead of Ilya's construction "at most $(k-1)$ of coin $k$", we could work also with "at most $(k-2)$ of coin $k$". Two points on the latter choice: (1) the argument works without the constraint for "large values of $n$"; (2) it makes any presence of both coins $k=1$ and $k=2$ to be essential.

$\lambda_1$ is a divisor of $n$, so there is a partition of $L_n$ whose only part is $\lambda_1$ (with some multiplicity).

We shall explain our algorithm. Assume we have coins of values among $1,2,\dots, n$ with some multiplicities, and for a total value of $2L_n$. That is,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot b_i=2L_n \qquad \text{for some $b_i\geq0$}.$$
Our aim is to pick some of them into the pocket so that the total value in the pocket will be $L_n$. Again, that means, there exist number $0\leq a_i\leq b_i$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i\cdot a_i=L_n.$$
Say that a coin $k$ is essential if there are at least $k-1$ coins of value $k$ outside the pocket; otherwise, we say $k$ is inessential. Notice that this notion of essential is dynamic, a coin may become inessential during the process!
At any stage, we maintain that the total $T$ in our pocket will be divisible by the largest essential number. At the beginning,  this holds by vacua.
Now, assume that at some moment (perhaps, at the very start) the two largest essential numbers are $k>\ell$. By our condition, $T$ is divisible by $k$; then we can take some (nonzero number of) coins of value $k$ so that the new $T$ will be divisible by $\mathop{\mathrm{lcm}}(k,\ell)$ (for simplicity, say we take those coins one by one), We have sufficiently many such coins to reach that, as $k$ is essential. After that, the largest essential number becomes either $k$ or $\ell$, so in any case we preserve the desired property. Then we repeat the step, using the new two largest essential numbers.
If $k$ is the only remaining essential number, we merely take coin of value $k$ at that step.
Notice that at any moment when we take coin of value $a$ the total in the pocket is divisible by $a$. This means that we cannot jump over $L_n$: if, at the end, the total in the pocket is at least $L_n$, then at some moment we had exactly $L_n$, as desired.
Suppose we run out of essential coins with fewer than a total of $L_n$ in our pocket. Surely, the process stops. But, we claim this event can not occur. Indeed, since all coins outside pocket are inessential, the total value of the coins outside the pocket does not exceed
\begin{align*}
  n(n-2)&+(n-1)(n-3)+\dots+2\cdot 0
  =\frac{(n-1)(n-2)(2n+3)}6 \\
  &\leq \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}2\leq\mathop{\mathrm{lcm}}(n,n-1,n-2)\leq L_n
\end{align*}
for $n\geq1$. The last equality is due to this result.
This leads to a contradiction because both set of coins (inside and outside our pocket) are not larger than $L_n$, with one inequality being strict. Hence the total is less than $2L_n$. The proof is now complete.

Thank you. I'm not sure though I understand how the algorithm works. Where do you start? with which coin? etc.

I thought that the explication was clear, but I have added some details. Is it better now? I start at the described moment, when all coins are outside the pocket. At that moment, I take the largest essential coin (in some quantity, depending on the value of the second largest essential coin).

$(4,4,3,3,3,2,2,1,1,1)$ is a partition of $2L_4$. Can you illustrate how to get a partition of $L_4$ from here?

I told that the method would work for large enough $n$.However, here it also works. You take two 3s (they were largest essentials, after this they become inessential), then two times a 2 (after which 2 becomes inessential) then three 1s in a sequence. After the second 1 you get what you want.

I realized that the estimate could be sharpened; now it works for all $n\geq 3$. Notice that the definition of an essential number has been changed.

I think we can drop the condition $n\geq3$ and say for any $n$ once you changed the definition for essential coins. Another issue is: your claim "at the end, all numbers become inessential", does not seem true. Take the example $(5^6,4^7,3^9,2^{13},1^9)\vdash 2L_5$. Following your new algorithm, you reach the desired value $L_5=60$ with the choices $(5^4,4^7,3^4)\vdash 60$. Yet, the coins $k=1, 2, 3$ are all still essential. I hope I did not make a mistake.

Tewodros, it is a matter of definition: you may proceed after you get a total of $L_n$ (then all costs eventually  become inessential), or stop.

@IlyaBogdanov: I have edited your proof a little bit. You can take it back if you don't agree.

@FedorPetrov: I appreciate the clarification. I just want Ilya's nice proof to be very clear.

The cited result is nice, but why using it? the trivial bound $L_n\geqslant lcm(n, n-1,n-2)\geqslant n(n-1)(n-2)/2$ also suffices here.

@FedorPetrov: you're right but I do want the inequalities to be strict.


We do not need the inequalities to be strict: if $L_n$ is left outside the pocket, we are still done. 2) I would prefer my proof since it was simpler, so if you don’t mind I would roll this back.


If you still need a zoom, we may try to do that tomorrow, but do you need?

@IlyaBogdanov: sure, you are welcome to put back your original proof.
